# Get gallery url (Nextgen)

Tags: urls, plugin-nextgen-gallery

Is there a way to get the gallery url of images. What I want to do is this:

image1 image2 image3 are in gallery "Pinto". When a user clicked for example on **image 1** and it pop-ups in lightbox I want there to show from wich gallery is the image and when the user clicked on that link to go to that gallery.

I found out how to get the gallery title - `<?php echo $gallery->title ?>` , but couldn't find  the right code for the gallery url.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

p.s. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind...i found the CODE (with the help of Alex Rabe), it is as follows:

```
<?php echo get_permalink( $image->pageid ) ?>
```